# Any way to remap the meta key with evil?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

Function modifiers in Emacs conflicts with many hotkeys I have (for example, conflicts with i3wm). By using evil I could use evil to avoid most of conflict hotkeys.

However, I do still need to use those function modifiers to use, for example, `M-x`, but it conflicts with other hotkeys. (For Emacs keymap, `ESC` can be used. But now `ESC` is used by evil, and is no longer a meta substitute.)

What I want to achieve is in normal mode, `;` acts as `ctrl`, and `'` as `alt`, the meta key.

I tried the following but none of them worked:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "'") 'event-apply-meta-modifier)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "'") 'meta)
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event-apply-meta-modifier` is only to be used in translation keymaps. You
should try

```
(define-key key-translation-map "'" 'event-apply-meta-modifier)
(define-key key-translation-map ";" 'event-apply-control-modifier)
```

This will also make it possible to use these keys in the middle of a key
sequence. If you want the keys to only work in normal state, you could use
something like

```
(defun evil-normal-state-filter (cmd)
  (and (fboundp 'evil-normal-state-p)
       (evil-normal-state-p)
       cmd))
(define-key key-translation-map "'"
  '(menu-item "" event-apply-meta-modifier :filter evil-normal-state-filter))
(define-key key-translation-map ";"
  '(menu-item "" event-apply-control-modifier :filter evil-normal-state-filter))
```

See info node `(elisp) Translation Keymaps` and `(elisp) Extended Menu Items`
for more information.

Comment: It works. Thanks!